# Sharded Counter RPCs and Calculated Cost Increases

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb, sharding

I'm doing some diagnostics on my sharded counter implementation for Google App Engine and I'm not sure where the additional RPCs are coming from.

The out-of-the-box version with 20 shards when getting non-cached counts for 20 counters gives the following info in Appstats:

```
RPCs
memcache.get                100  
memcache.set                80  
memcache.del                0  
datastore.get               60  
datastore_commit            0  
datastore_put               0  
datastore_begin_transaction 0

Billed Ops  
datastore_read              420  
datastore_write             0  

Cost                        29,400
```

For reference, here is the counter code:

```
class GeneralCounterShard(ndb.Model):
    """Shards for each named counter."""
    count = ndb.IntegerProperty(default=0)


def get_count(name):
    """Retrieve the value for a given sharded counter.
    Args:
        name: The name of the counter.
    Returns:
        Integer; the cumulative count of all sharded counters for the given
            counter name.
    """
    total = memcache.get(name)
    if total is None:
        total = 0
        all_keys = GeneralCounterShardConfig.all_keys(name)
        for counter in ndb.get_multi(all_keys):
            if counter is not None:
                total += counter.count
        memcache.add(name, total, 60)
    return total
```

When I change the sharded counter code to make the get_count a "classmethod" of the GeneralCounterShard class, the RPCs change drastically:

```
RPCs
memcache.get                100  
memcache.set                80  
memcache.del                20  
datastore.get               80  
datastore_commit            20  
datastore_put               20  
datastore_begin_transaction 20

Billed Ops
datastore_read              440  
datastore_write             60   

Cost                        36,800
```

For reference, here is the change:

```
class GeneralShardedCounter(ndb.Model):

    count = ndb.IntegerProperty(default=0)

    @classmethod
    def get_count(name):

        total = memcache.get(name)
        if total is None:
            total = 0
            all_keys = GeneralShardedCounterConfig.all_keys(name)
            for counter in ndb.get_multi(all_keys):
                if counter is not None:
                    total += counter.count
            memcache.add(name, total, 60)
        return total
```

In review, the difference between the two is:

```
RPCs
memcache.get                +0  
memcache.set                +0  
memcache.del                +20  
datastore.get               +20  
datastore_commit            +20  
datastore_put               +20  
datastore_begin_transaction +20 

Billed Ops
datastore_read              +20  
datastore_write             +60  

Cost                        +7,400
```

What would cause the jump in RPCs and reads and writes just by making one method a classmethod of an ndb model?

Comment: I suspect the answer almost certainly lies in ndb's built-in entity caching, so I imagine you'd see, say, `+n` `memcache.del` calls for a counter with `n` shards. What I don't get is exactly how the `@classmethod` changes that (I'm no python internals expert). Can you post the line(s) where you call `get_count()`?

Comment: A class method takes that class name as the first argument.  It isn't clear to me if that is the same as your counter name.  Do you want to use a static method instead?

Comment: So, it looks like a false positive. I didn't realize the datastore created a record for the counter config, but that's what the other 20 puts are coming from. One per counter. The first time I ran this the datastore was empty.